# Update kuduscript with php 8

Tags: php, azure, github, php-8, kudu

We are trying to update our azure web app service to php 8.
In deployment we use kudu and app service build service.

When we try to deploy after changing to php 8 in the code we get the error that php command is not found.
And when we run compose installer we can install due to composer.lock requiering php 8.0

The only source for php 7.3 (which specifies that is the problem) is the kudu script. However we have not found a decent way of updating this to php 8. Has anyone done this?

kudu_ssh_user@:/$ php --version
PHP 7.3.27 (cli) (built: Mar 18 2021 08:28:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: Your Azure App Service is Linux or Windows ? As of now support for PHP 8 is available only for App Service Linux instances.

Comment: @Harshitha 
Yeah we did check that and it is based in Linux. So support for php 8 should not be a problem. I belive it is the Kuduscript itself. When we update to php 8 in azure Kudu doesnt have any php versions to read off.